# Convert comma delimited string to sas array

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a javascript array that is passed to a sas program as a string, for example

```
"['apple (123)','banana (456)','cherries (789)']"
```

Can someone show me how to convert this string into a sas array in sas programming language? I'm not very familiar with sas. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?  Also how to structure the result depends on how you want to use it.  SAS doesn't really have arrays (unless you are using IML). An "array" in SAS is just a utility for making reference to a series of actual variables easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do.  Is the javascript passing the variable in as a macro variable or is there an assignment in a data step?

The following will break the string apart into separate variables:

```
data want;                                                                                                                              
keep x1-x3;                                                                                                                             

array x[3] $20;                                                                                                                         
col1 = "['apple (123)','banana (456)','cherries (789)']" ;                                                                              
col1 = compress(col1,"'[]");                                                                                                            
j=1;                                                                                                                                    
do i=1 by 1 while(scan(col1,i,',') ^='');                                                                                               
  x[j]=scan(col1,i,',');                                                                                                                  
  j=j+1;                                                                                                                         
end;                                                                                                                    
run;
```